# Regex that does not contain the substring 010

Tags: regex, binary

I'm trying to write a regex expression to exclude binary strings that contain `010`.
I'm not quite sure what to write.

I have this to start with but I'm not too sure what to do:

```
1*(0+10)*
```

Thank you!

Comment: In practice, I would recommend two regular expressions if possible: `!/010/ && /whateverelse/`

Comment: If this is for an automata class, then expand the *accepted* forms.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to match binary string (strings which contain only `1`'s and `0`'s) but exclude strings which contain the string `010`, perhaps use something like this:

```
^((?!010)[01])*$
```

This will match any sequence of zero or more `0` or `1` characters such that the sequence does not contain the substring `010`. The start (`^`) and end (`$`) anchors will ensure that no additional characters are allowed in the input string.

Comment: This requires Perl-compatible regex, while it looks like the OP is looking for a pure BRE.

Answer (score 0):

Your attempt requires any stretch of zeros to be followed by 10 which is clearly a violation of your constraint. Instead, require any 1 to be followed by at least one more, or end of string.

```
(0*(1(1+|$))*)*
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an anchored negative look ahead:

```
^(?!.*010)[01]+$
```